# Creating a directory in year\10-oct\date format

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a small script that will allow me to copy/delete files from one server to another.

The end result should have the folders in `\\\Serveraddress\folder\2013\10-Oct\22\text.log` format

I am stumped on how to create the year month and day folders.

I'm thinking it should look something like this; but honestly I don't know.

```
mkdir \\Serveraddress\folder\yearfolder
mkdir \\Serveraddress\folder\2013\monthfolder
mkdir \\Serveraddress\folder\2013\10-Oct\dayfolder
copy \\Serveraddress\folder\*.log \\Serveraddress\folder\year\month\day\
del \\Serveraddress\folder\*.log
```

This will end up being run twice a day and I'd like to get it as automated as possible.
Any Tips?

Comment: maybe it's easier through power shell...

Comment: Tip is to learn batch file programming. Good luck!! With Powershell should be easier to program but what about config? I guess not much since it is only some permissions needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires XP Pro and higher for Wmic.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

if "%mm%"=="01" set "mmm=Jan"
if "%mm%"=="02" set "mmm=Feb"
if "%mm%"=="03" set "mmm=Mar"
if "%mm%"=="04" set "mmm=Apr"
if "%mm%"=="05" set "mmm=May"
if "%mm%"=="06" set "mmm=Jun"
if "%mm%"=="07" set "mmm=Jul"
if "%mm%"=="08" set "mmm=Aug"
if "%mm%"=="09" set "mmm=Sep"
if "%mm%"=="10" set "mmm=Oct"
if "%mm%"=="11" set "mmm=Nov"
if "%mm%"=="12" set "mmm=Dec"

mkdir "\\Serveraddress\folder\%yyyy%\%mm%-%mmm%\%dd%" 2>nul
move "\\Serveraddress\folder\*.log" "\\Serveraddress\folder\%yyyy%\%mm%-%mmm%\%dd%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set 1=jan
set 2=feb
set 3=mar
set 4=apr
set 5=may
set 6=jun
set 7=jul
set 8=aug
set 9=sept
set 10=oct
set 11=nov
set 12=dec
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('echo %date%') do (md "\\Serveraddress\folder\%%l\%%j-!%%j!\%%k" & move "\\Serveraddress\folder\*.log" "\\Serveraddress\folder\%%l\%%j-!%%j!\%%k")
```

this should work, if not comment.